# How to add a defined radius between two curves in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

Is there a way to add a defined radius between two curves in geometry nodes?
(The two curves are also defined in GN.)

[image]

Update:
This is what happens when I use Bezier Segments with the proposed solution. The vertical curve is extended to infinity in -Z and the Radius is fallen apart. I tried to reverse one or the other curve but it doesn't help:

[image]

This is such an important function (for creating procedural designs from scratch) that it would be great if some developer could come up with a proper fillet solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, as it stands you currently have to roundtrip convert to mesh and back to do that.

You have to convert the curve to mesh with a *Curve to Mesh* node, to be able to use a *Merge by Distance* so you can convert back to a bezier curve and fillet.

[image]

This shouldn't be much of a problem for straight segments only, but can cause loss of fidelity if you have curved splines.

Alternatively you can save a few steps by instead starting with a *Mesh Line* primitive instead, and just converting to curve afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I hoped there is a way to remain in "curves territory" as the tangent is better defined as with meshes. Also I have more curves which needs to be connected with different radii so I have to see if I can do that with the converted meshes.
Such a radius function between curves is so essential, I wonder why it is still missing from the GN toolbox.

Comment: @Steve But the radius is done on a curve in this answer... the problem is just merging the two connecting points together - the _Merge by Distance_ needs a mesh. But afterwards Duarte converts the mesh back to a curve and sets the radius. It's not that there is no such function for curves, the problem is your curves are not connected - a _Join Geometry_ node does not merge the control points.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry and thanks. I'm coming from a NURBS workflow (Alias) where curves are treated separately. "Attaching" them would change their mathematical definition (introduce a multi-knot at the attachment position, which is not desirable in Alias). Converting the curve to a mesh an then back again is actually changing the curve especially if it's curved a lot. (I guess that was Dueart's comment.)
I need to get my head around the way Blender is working with curves.

Comment: I tested the above setup and it only works with lines. With my original setup (with two Bezier Segments) it creates some very strange and broken curves as a result.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue with roundtrip to mesh and back, it is only lossless for straight curve segments. The minute you use curved or tesselated bezier segments, the subdivisions causes losses when converted to mesh.

Comment: I updated the original post with a resulting image. It's not just that the curve looses it's form but it seem to completely mess up the radius.

Comment: Lower the resolution of your bezier segments to 1.

Comment: Lowering it to 1, removes the "curvature" of the curve making it to a straight line. That solved the problem of the weird radius but also kind of destroys the curve. I marked your solution as the Answer as there seems to be no pure curve way to achieve this.

Comment: you can capture bezier data (handle positions), and restore it after converting back to curve

Comment: Does that help when the curve segments are set to 1? (Straight) How do I capture them? I tried with "Curve Handle Position" and then "Set Handle Position" for Left and Right and then "Join Geometry" but that did not do anything.