Fillet High Resolution Arc joined to line in Geometry Nodes
Trying to create fillet against arc with high resolution will cause it to crumble when making radius to large.
I think fillet node only adds extra vertexes, so for high resolution curve are not correctly removed to match fillet.
How would i go about calculating which vertex on arc to remove?

Used Node from below video to join curves
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJx416QCV7w
File with curves on it
https://blend-exchange.com/b/eN1WVWOP

To clarify what you are trying to achieve. In your GN modifier, you are creating two curves, each made of an Arc and of a Line. In one case, there are only 4 vertices along the arc. In the second case, there are 256. Do you try to achieve the same shape as the first one, with the second case ? For that, you would like to delete control points from the arc ? Or would you like to limit the angle (actually 270°) ?

Delete control points and create correct fillet (to tangent?) between arc and line. One with 4 verts looses shape of arc, but has correct fillet.

Are you looking for a solution in this configuration only (one line and one arc), or a general solution and this case is just an illustration ?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/310103/how-to-add-a-defined-radius-between-two-curves-in-geometry-nodes/310106#310106 - this post in comments talk of curved line but seems no solution

This just illustration. - though between a line and curved line

just this configuration, once i can work way to do it.  I should be fine to use more generally myself.
